# Firestore how to add a new map in array with setDoc even if array with same value exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a new map in array named `players` but everytime i try to add it with this code

```
            await setDoc(
                doc(firestore, 'gambles', gambleId),
                {
                    players: arrayUnion({
                        balanceDrop: silver,
                        id: userId,
                        login: userData.login
                    }),
                    totalPlayers: increment(1),
                    totalSilver: Number(gambleData?.totalSilver) + Number(silver)
                },
                { merge: true }
            );
```

and there is already a map with same values another map is not being created only `totalSilver` and `totalPlayers` values are being updated I just want another map even if values are the same
[image]

Comment: did you think about using unique identifier for each map and including it in the data.?

Comment: nah, but actually this might be the best solution i think and easiest to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayUnion` is behaving exactly as it's supposed to here.  It will not add new array elements that are the same as any existing elements.  That's why it's called a "union" operation as opposed to a "push" operation.  This is made clear in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

> `arrayUnion()` adds elements to an array but only elements not already present.

If you want to add a duplicate element, you have to first read the document, modify the array in memory to contain whatever duplicates you want, then update the array field back to the document.